# Out of stack space error in IE11 when using aureliajs and babel-polyfill

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, aurelia, babeljs

I'm setting up my aurelia app like this:

```
import "babel-polyfill";    

export function configure(aurelia) {
    // some config code
}
```

And that's the error I'm getting:

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [3] (SystemJS) Error: Out of stack space
       at d (eval code:6:23405)
       at d (eval code:6:23405)
       at d (eval code:6:23405)
       at d (eval code:6:23405)
       at d (eval code:6:23405)
       at d (eval code:6:23405)
       at d (eval code:6:23405)
       at d (eval code:6:23405)
       at d (eval code:6:23405)
       at d (eval code:6:23405)
    Evaluating http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@2.4.1/modules/es6.map.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@2.4.1/shim.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-polyfill@6.13.0/lib/index.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-polyfill@6.13.0.js
    Error loading http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/babel-polyfill@6.13.0.js
```

Works ok if I don't include `babel-polyfill` but not using it is not a workaround because I need to use it. The question here is: how do I continue using babel-polyfill without experiencing this error?

Comment: Soooo... Why the downvote?

Comment: If I had to guess, the down vote is due to the fact that you only state that you are having an issue, there is no explicit question. You obviously have a work around (don't use `babel-polyfill`), what is it you need?

Comment: Not using `babel-polyfill` is not a workaround because I need to use it :). So my need is to use this lib and not have this error :).

Comment: So, edit the question and add that information. :)

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work, I had to change the `index.html` to contain this:

```
System.import('scripts/core-js.js')
      .then(function() {
        System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
       });
```

I downloaded the `core-js.js` file from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zloirock/core-js/master/client/core.js though you can probably get it from npm and I placed it in the scripts folder. I'm sure you can put it anywhere as long as the above import is pointing to it.

Comment: Looks promising, I'll check it out later today. Thank you very much. I already gave up on that :).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the question until just last night. I just had this same type of error the other day and that was how I solved it. Please let me know if it works!